# How to read in multiple .csv files, merge and create new column?

Tags: r

I wish to read in multiple .csv files from a folder, located on my desktop, merge all these .csv files into one data.frame and create a column that contains the name of each file.

I have tried:

```
my.path <- "C:/Users/JB/Desktop/RawFiles/"
filenames <- paste(my.path, list.files(path=my.path), sep="/")
my.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(x,'\\.')[[1]][1])))
```

However, `my.dt$name` doesn't contain the filename of the .csv. Rather, it contains the location of the file. For example, `head(my.dt, 3)` produces:

```
 name
1 C:/Users/JB/Desktop/RawFiles//Analysis_01122016
2 C:/Users/JB/Desktop/RawFiles//Analysis_01122016
3 C:/Users/JB/Desktop/RawFiles//Analysis_01122016
```

How can I edit this so `my.dt$name` only produces the file.name? My anticipated output would be:

```
name
    1 Analysis_01122016
    2 Analysis_01122016
    3 Analysis_01122016
```

Thanks!

Comment: That `strplit` is splitting on the period `.` and taking the first part.  So all it's doing is dropping the extension (or more, if any filenames have a period in it)

Comment: Also, your `sep = "/"` seems to be adding an extra slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use a variable for the path; the `full.names = TRUE` argument to `list.files` will do that for you.

If you want just the file name and extension, you can use:

```
basename("full/path/to/myfile.csv")
```

If you want to remove the extension too:

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename("full/path/to/myfile.csv"))
```

So you can do something like this with your code:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/JB/Desktop/RawFiles", full.names = TRUE)
my.df <- do.call(rbind,
                 lapply(filenames, function(x) 
                                   cbind(read.csv(x), 
                                   name = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))))
```

But there are cleaner solutions using tools such as `plyr::ldply` or `data.table` and you'll find examples in other answers with the right search.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file path on "/" with strsplit(), and grab the last element of the resulting vector.

```
files <- list.files("~/Dropbox/structure_simulations/str_in/k2",full.names = T)

df <- lapply(files,function(e) {
  tmp <- read.csv(e)
  name <- unlist(strsplit(e,"/"))[length(unlist(strsplit(e,"/")))] 
  name <- unlist(strsplit(name,"\\."))[1]
  tmp$name <- name
  tmp
  })
df <- do.call(rbind,df)
```